# Поочерёдная запись id в файл python vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

vk_api позволяет получить информацию о фотографии через photos.get

```
getph = (vk.photos.get(owner_id=-127755, album_id = 'wall', count=1))
```

далее я записываю owner_id и id в файл, который дальше использую в своих целях.
Мне нужно, чтобы процесс происходил примерно по такому пути

1. возвращает данные 1 фотографии
2. беру нужные мне данные
3. записываю их в файл
4. использую дальше
5. возвращает данные 2 фотографии
   ... и так далее. 
   Но есть одна загвоздка, count в .get не даёт рассматривать фото по очереди, а лишь задаёт их кол-во. Никак не пойму, что мне теперь делать, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/photos.get `offset - отступ, необходимый для получения определенного подмножества записей. 
положительное число`

Comment: ааа, а я думал это как отступ между выбранными фотографиями, т.е шаг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У метода [photos.get](https://vk.com/dev/photos.get) есть параметр **offset**, который позволяет сделать отступ от начала альбома. Таким образом, циклом

```py
for i in range(5):
    vk.photos.get(owner_id=-127755, album_id = 'wall', count=1, offset=i)
```

Можно поочередно перебрать 5 фотографий.

---

Но я бы на Вашем месте получил всю пачку фотографий (`count=1000`) и далее шёл бы по этой пачке и собирал необходимую информацию. Таким образом не будут делаться запросы для каждой фотографии по отдельности (у ВК есть "защита" от частых обращений к API).

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Про count тоже спасибо, но мне это скорее всего не понадобится, у меня дальше всё равно идёт обращение к api отдельно с каждой фоткой